# Options to start over

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am working in a Magento store that was developed 2 years ago by other developers. I updated the Magento version, patches, etc. I also "cleaned" old files and folders but we still have unused files in the FTP, old themes folders and even extensions that we don't need anymore (I just deactivated it).

Now the company decided to do a complete redesign of the website. So, what is my best option?

Should I just start a new Magento installation to "clean" everything and import the customer/products/sales data? I feel that doing this I would have more "control" over the store. At the same time, I am afraid that we will lost data, since Magento DB is very complex.

Should I just "clean" whatever I can and install a new theme over the same website?

I appreciate any ideas or experiences that you guys had with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need to install new magento. You wrote we decide to redesign the site so best approach is use  updated Magento version that you recently did. By using this you don't need to worried about tables, files as well as importing data such as orders, products, customers etc.

Answer (score 2):

What I have done in the past is left the database intact and install a new instance of magento over it.  Going through the db and removing old tables that aren't used anymore is a good idea, although they most likely won't be an issue unless they are huge or cause installation integrity conflicts.

Don't forget to double check your core_config_data table to be sure there aren't any custom values causing issues.  Cookies domain or theme settings that no longer are relevant, although fallbacks should ensure nothing breaks.

Truncate your log tables and other large temporary tables if you want to.

So, for reassurance, I've done this many times without much, if any, issues.

Comment: Thanks for the insights! How about your CMS pages and blocks? Can you keep them with the new theme as well?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Could you provide an example?

Comment: I actually already start the project, thank you for your comment. I was saying that: I have a page in my website (created in the backend of Magento) and I change the Magento files in my server (without changing the DB) . Would that affect my page in Magento? I know that the page id, name and content are in the DB, but the layout files will change and maybe this could be a conflict.

Comment: Anyway, we ended up not changing the Magento installation and the company decided to just make some layout changes. Thanks again!